# I am new to Regular Expressions . Why isn't this match working in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

This is my code :-

```
$_ = " 511 1 1 ;";
$line = "511 1 1";

if(m/" ".$line/){
       print "reached\n";
}
```

I want the match to occur but it's not happening.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo , it still is not working

Comment: I made some edits . Please check them.

Comment: You should create a new question, not fully change the question, otherwise you'll invalidate all the answers already posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/" ".$line/` matches literal `" "` then any char except newline (`.`) and finally `511 1 1`

You probably want just `/ $line/`

Comment: Maybe emphasize that what goes between `m/.../` is a single regular expression, not a snippet of Perl code.

Comment: Clearer still: Just like for `"..."`, the insides of `/.../` is not executed as Perl code.

Answer (score 0):

I need a comparative subject string, i.e: `if this ($_) matches this (m/ $line/)`

```
$_ = " 511 1 1 ;";
$line = "511 1 1";

if ($_ =~ m/ $line/) {
    print "reached\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add space before `$line` to do the match, may be you want to add word boundary in order to not match `1511 1 1`:

```
$_ = " 511 1 1 ;";
$line = "511 1 1";
print "reached\n" if /\b$line\b/;
```